# Workaround for debug symbol error with auto member function?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, c++14

There seems to be an issue with debug symbols and auto.

I have an auto function in a class:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
struct binary_expr {
    auto operator()(std::size_t i){
        return 1;
    }
};

int main(){
    binary_expr<double> b;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile with G++ (4.8.2) and -g, I have this error:

```
g++ -g -std=c++1y auto.cpp
auto.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct binary_expr<double>’:
auto.cpp:11:25:   required from here
auto.cpp:4:8: internal compiler error: in gen_type_die_with_usage, at dwarf2out.c:19484
 struct binary_expr {
        ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://bugs.gentoo.org/> for instructions.
```

With clang++ (3.4) and -g, I have this:

```
clang++ -g -std=c++1y auto.cpp
error: debug information for auto is not yet supported
1 error generated.
```

If I remove the -g or set the type explicitly, it works perfectly.

Isn't clang++ supposed to be C++14 feature complete ?

Is there a workaround for these limitations or I'm screwed ?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to return a `T` from your `operator()`; If that's the case then I don't see a single reason for making the compiler deduce the return type. Why not explicitly state `T` as the return type?

Comment: Compiles with gcc 4.9. As for clang being *feature complete*, emitting debug info is not a language feature.

Comment: @Jeffrey That is a simplified case, in the case I want, that is not a a T but the deduction can be complicated if auto is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after some time, the only workaround I have found is to make the function template, pretty stupid workaround... Apparently, clang has no problem with auto functions that are template. I don't know if this works in every case, but until now it had worked for me.

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
struct binary_expr {
    template<typename E = void>
    auto operator()(std::size_t i){
        return 1;
    }
};

int main(){
    binary_expr<double> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This now seems to works on Clang 3.5 SVN. [**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/802bdfc027d312d2). It seems that the culprit was a commit from May 2013, see this [**message**](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20130520/080526.html) on the Clang mailing list.

> PR16091: Error when attempting to emit debug info for undeduced auto
>   return types
>
> Perhaps we should just suppress this, rather than erroring, but since
>   we have the infrastructure for it I figured I'd use it - if this is
>   determined to be not the right thing we should probably remove that
>   infrastructure entirely. I guess it's lying around from the early days
>   of implementing debug info support.

```
// RUN: %clang_cc1 -emit-llvm-only -std=c++1y -g %s 2>&1 | FileCheck %s
2   
3   struct foo {
4     auto func(); // CHECK: error: debug information for auto is not yet supported
5   };
6   
7   foo f;
```

However, I cannot find the commit that removed this info, perhaps there was an improvement that now prevents that this behavior is being triggered.

Comment: Actually no, it appears to be still not fixed.  Your version of the test case does work, agreed, but remove the `b(0)` instantiation, and its broken again: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e40517a78fedd48